# Programmatically perform click in ultragrid cell

Tags: vb.net, click, ultrawingrid

I have a `UltraGrid` with a few columns that looks like this :

```
------------------------
| Name | Year | Audit  |
------------------------
| John | 2012 |[Button]|
------------------------
| Bill | 2013 |[Button]|
------------------------
```

I want to perform a click on the selected row's Audit column button **at runtime with a keyboard shortcut**. Is that possible ? Something like this (does not exists)

```
myUltraGrid.ActiveRow.Cells("Audit").CellButton.PerformClick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on a cell of `Button Style` triggers the event `ClickCellButton`. This event receives the `CellEventArgs` containing information about the cell clicked. You could easily refactor your code to separate the action executed in this event and make that action callable from outside the event (whenever you need to execute the action)

```
' Your clickCellButton will be refactored to extract in a separate method '
' the action for every cell button'
Private Sub grd_ClickCellButton(sender as object, e as CellEventArgs)
    Try
        if e.Cell.Column.Key == "Audit" Then
            ActionForCellAudit(e.Cell.Row)
        elseif (e.Cell.Column.Key == "key2" Then
            ActionForCellButton1()
        elseif (e.Cell.Column.Key == "key3" Then
            ActionForCellButton1()
    Catch(a As Exception)
        MessageBox.Show(x.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ActionForCellAudit(row As UltraGridRow)
     ' The action required if clicking the Audit cell button is here'
End Sub
......
```

Now when you need to execute the same action elsewhere you extract the info about the `ActiveRow` and call the `ActionForCellAudit`

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
                          Handles Form1.KeyDown
    ' Supposing the CTRL+F5 is the shortcut defined to execute the ActionForCellAudit
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 AndAlso e.Control = True then
        if grd.ActiveRow IsNot Nothing AndAlso grd.ActiveRow.IsDataRow Then
            ActionForCellAudit(grd.ActiveRow)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: With this approach I will have to click it manually no ? I need to click it programmatically at runtime. If I click the cell something happens but I want to add a keyboard shortcut to the button cell

Comment: If you need a keyboard shortcut then you need to handle this in the KeyDown event of the Form and call the Action required by the shortcut (this will work also if the grid doesn't have the focus)

Comment: This is what I did. I'm catching the shortcut. The action however would be a simulation of click on this column.. I can't find how to perform a click from the code...

Comment: The key factor here is: What do you do when the user clicks manually on that cell? Extract that code in a method and call that method from the shortcut handler as shown above

Comment: Ok I guess this is what i'm going to do... I can't believe there is no such thing as `PerformClick()` for a cell button

Comment: There is a method called [PerformAction](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~PerformAction(UltraGridAction).html) and also the collection of [KeyActionMappings](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo~KeyActionMappings.html) but I am not sure that with these object you could achieve the result required